# Elixir / Phoenix: Views for channels?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm creating a chat app and I have a bunch of channel messages. Here's one of them:

```
def handle_in("read", %{ "chat_id" => chat_id }, socket) do
  user_id = socket.assigns[:id]

  ts = DateTime.utc_now
  case ChatManager.mark_as_read({user_id, chat_id, ts}) do
    {:ok, chat_user} ->
      last_read_at_unix = chat_user.last_read_at |> TimeConverter.ecto_to_unix
      {:reply, {:ok, %{ chat_id: chat_id, last_read_at: last_read_at_unix }}, socket}
    {:error, changeset} ->
      {:reply, {:error, %{errors: changeset.errors}}, socket}
  end
end
```

Can I use phoenix Views to separate my presentation / response logic? This way I can just quickly go to a view file and see what is returned by each message.

Comment: Yes, you can use Phoenix views in your channels. Just call MyView.render ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phoenix Views are just normal modules with functions in them.

You can either call those functions directly:

```
MyApp.Web.ChatView.render("message.json", %{message: my_message})
```

Or use a `Phoenix.View` function which would call the `render/2` function of your view:

```
Phoenix.View.render_one(MyApp.Web.ChatView, "message.json", message: my_message)
```

The `Phoenix.View` functions have a few advantages if your arguments are more dynamic (for example if you pass `nil` as the message).

Consult the [Phoenix.View documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html) for details on those convenience functions.

When building a large application, it makes sense to have `.json` templates for all your models because you'll need to pass json around in API responses, as channel messages or serialized messages in a message queue. The views you've already written are reusable for all of those cases.

Comment: Just a note, using `Phoenix.View.render/3` returns a tuple like `{:safe, binary_data}`, you can not directly pipe it into client. Use `Phoenix.View.render_to_string/3` or `Phoenix.View.render_to_iodata/3` if you want the output directly.

Comment: Good note although I haven't observed this behaviour when rendering json.

Comment: I think using `render` in views is fine, but when you need the raw string you should know this. I'm not sure though.